# Error: passing 'const xxx' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers

Tags: class, object, compiler-errors, constants

I am trying to implement bigint class in c++, it's not completed yet, i have encountered some errors that i am unable understand.

I have erased all other functions (as they are unnecessary in this case)
and karatsuba is not yet completed (but that should't pose a problem in this case).

In the multiply function (overloaded * ) my compiler gives an error:

> passing 'const BigInt' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

at line

```
 ans.a = karatsuba(n,m);
```

I understand that this would occur when i am trying to change a constant object or object passed to a constant function, in my case i am merely creating a new vector and passing it to karatsuba function. 
Removing const from overloded * gets rid of this error.

So,does this mean that a constant function can't change anything at all? (including local variables?)

```
class BigInt {

    typedef long long int ll;
    typedef vector<int> vi;
    #define p10 1000000000;
    #define range 9
    vi a;
    bool sign;
    public:

    BigInt operator * (const BigInt &num) const
    {
        vi n(a.begin(),a.end()),m(num.a.begin(),num.a.end());
        BigInt ans;
        ans.sign = !(sign ^ num.sign);
        while(n.size()<m.size()) n.push_back(0);
        while(n.size()>m.size()) m.push_back(0);
        ans.a = karatsuba(n,m);
        return ans;
    }

    vi karatsuba(vi a,vi b)
    {
        int n = a.size();
        if(n <= 16)
        {  
             // some code
        }
             // some code
        return a;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after googling a bit more, i realized that this pointer is implicitly passed to the oveloaded * and then on to karatsuba (as it is a member function of the class), and as karatsuba is not a constant function, there is no guarantee that it won't change the object contents, hence this error is triggered.
One solution is to declare karatsuba as static, as static member functions don't receive this pointer (they can even be called with out a class object simply using :: operator) , read more about them from here [Static data members and member functions.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_static_members.htm)

All that is needed to be changed is :-

```
static vi karatsuba(vi a,vi b)
{
    int n = a.size();
    if(n <= 16)
    {  
         // some code
    }
         // some code
    return a;
}
```